# Google QPX Express

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-qpx-express-api

i am trying to use google QPX Express API for ASP.NET in order to read flights with cheap price but stuck on the below code.please share me any idea .

```
  // Passengers
        PassengerCounts passengers = new PassengerCounts();
        passengers.AdultCount = 2;

        // Slice
        List<SliceInput> slices = new List<SliceInput>();

        SliceInput slice = new SliceInput();
        slice.Origin = "ADD";
        slice.Destination = "NBO";
        slice.Date = "2015-10-29";
        slices.Add(slice);


        // Options request
        TripOptionsRequest tripOptions = new TripOptionsRequest();
        tripOptions.Passengers = passengers;
        tripOptions.Solutions = 10;
        tripOptions.Slice = slices;
```

Regards,

Comment: You need to help us out a little. Is there an error?  Whats the problem with you code currently?

Comment: there is no problem on the code. but my question is what should i do next to fetch the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send your request against the authenticated service and call execute.

```
        QPXExpressService service = new QPXExpressService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            ApiKey = "xxxx",
            ApplicationName = "Daimto QPX Express Sample",
        });

        TripsSearchRequest x = new TripsSearchRequest();
        x.Request = new TripOptionsRequest();
        x.Request.Passengers = new PassengerCounts { AdultCount = 2 };
        x.Request.Slice = new List<SliceInput>();
        x.Request.Slice.Add(new SliceInput() { Origin = "ADD", Destination = "NBO", Date = "2015-10-29" });
        x.Request.Solutions = 10;
        var result = service.Trips.Search(x).Execute();
```

Comment: thanks for your replay. i have checked it but there is an error on the line             x.Request.Slice = new List<SliceInput>(); . it is saying  cannot implicitly convert type system.collections.generic.list to system.collections.generic.IList. please one more help.